# MySQL SELECT statement COUNT error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, ms-access

***EDIT*** - Using *PHP* I made an ODBC connection to a local Access database

I'm getting the following error:

`Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]COUNT field incorrect , SQL state 07001 in SQLExecDirect in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpanel\modelsearch\test.php on line 37
Error in SQL`

I have a feeling some of the syntax is wrong here for an ODBC connection

```
$sql="SELECT `ITEM`, `DESCRIPTION`, `CUS_LOC_NAME`, `MECH_REL_BY`, `PM_DESIGN`, `SHIP_ACTUAL`, `HPL`, `WO_LINE`, `SO` FROM `Schedule` WHERE `HPL` <> 'PART' AND (LEFT(`DESCRIPTION`,6)=?) AND (LEFT(`CUS_LOC_NAME`,6)=?)";
```

This statement works fine in Access, but its not translating to MySQL very well. What syntax am i missing here?

FULL CODE  **RECENTLY EDITED TO REMOVE PDO STATEMENT**:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

 $sql="SELECT `ITEM`, `DESCRIPTION`, `CUS_LOC_NAME`, `MECH_REL_BY`, `PM_DESIGN`, `SHIP_ACTUAL`, `HPL`, `WO_LINE`, `SO` FROM `Schedule` WHERE `HPL` <> 'PART' AND (LEFT(`DESCRIPTION`,6)=?) AND (LEFT(`CUS_LOC_NAME`,6)=?)";
 $rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
 if (!$rs) {
   exit("Error in SQL");
 } 

 echo "<table><tr>";
 echo "<th>ITEM</th>";
 echo "<th>DESCRIPTION</th>";
 echo "<th>CUS_LOC_NAME</th>";
 echo "<th>MECH_REL_BY</th>";
 echo "<th>PM_DESIGN</th>";
 echo "<th>SHIP_ACTUAL</th>";
 echo "<th>HPL</th>";
 echo "<th>WO_LINE</th>";
 echo "<th>SO</th></tr>";

 while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
   $item=odbc_result($rs,"ITEM");
   $desc=odbc_result($rs,"DESCRIPTION");
   $cus=odbc_result($rs,"CUS_LOC_NAME");
   $mech=odbc_result($rs,"MECH_REL_BY");
   $pm_design=odbc_result($rs,"PM_DESIGN");
   $ship=odbc_result($rs,"SHIP_ACTUAL");
   $hpl=odbc_result($rs,"HPL");
   $wo=odbc_result($rs,"WO_LINE");
   $so=odbc_result($rs,"SO");

   echo "<tr><td>$item</td>";
   echo "<td>$desc</td>";
   echo "<td>$cus</td>";
   echo "<td>$mech</td>";
   echo "<td>$pm_design</td>";
   echo "<td>$ship</td>";
   echo "<td>$hpl</td>";
   echo "<td>$wo</td>";
   echo "<td>$so</td></tr>";
 }
odbc_close($conn);
echo "</table>";


?>
```

THE error is at this line: `$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

This code works just fine when I edit the $sql statement to remove the ands:

```
$sql="SELECT `ITEM`, `DESCRIPTION`, `CUS_LOC_NAME`, `MECH_REL_BY`, `PM_DESIGN`, `SHIP_ACTUAL`, `HPL`, `WO_LINE`, `SO` FROM `Schedule` WHERE `HPL` <> 'PART'";
```

So the obvious error is the LEFT() functions. Can someone advise on how to approach this? Also, I'm not sure what the =? means.

Comment: The query looks fine to me. Are you sure the parameters are being bound properly? Post your code.

Comment: Yup miken32 and I have the same thought. It looks fine. sqlfiddle perhaps? So we could play a little :)

Comment: I just posted the entire code. Also, in my original post I failed to mention that im using PHP and making the ODBC connection. I apologize.

Comment: You have PDO initialization but you don't use it after that? Also you are sending a parameterized query to the database as a regular query. How is it supposed to know what the value of ? is supposed to be? Use `odbc_prepare()` or continue to use PDO, which is the preferred method.

Comment: I think that's my question. I do not know what the question mark (?) means. It seems to work fine in Access but I think its the culprit when using php odbc call.

Comment: Someone (company network) made an Excel file that connects to an Access database where they used similar code above. The Excel file works great calling the Access database entries, but not for me

Comment: This code would not work in Access any more than MySQL. You have to tell the database what values to put in place for the placeholders. You're creating `$db` at the outset, continue using it and get rid of the `odbc_*()` functions. [See here](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) on how to use PDO for prepared statements.

Comment: ...I'm confused...If i edit the $sql to remove the AND statements it works just fine. This works in both Access and if I edit the statement to remove both the ANDs it works fine, but you are telling me this wont work. Why am I seeing data then?

Comment: Guys... The PDO initialization is for something completely different. Please ignore. I'm not using PDO for an ODBC connection. I'm strictly focusing on the ODBC connection.

Comment: Because the AND... statements are causing the problem. As already stated, during execution in Access the ? are replaced in your query by the values that should be looked up. For the query to work properly replace the ? by whatever it is you are looking for in the database.

Comment: I've updated my answer to remove the PDO stuff. If you're asking a DB related question, best to remove unrelated DB code first ;)

Comment: Thank you @user2779697. I wasn't sure what the ? meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem was that your query included placeholders (`?`) for a prepared statement, but you were treating it as a normal query. Prepared statements need to be prepared with `odbc_prepare()` and then executed with `odbc_execute()`.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");

$conn = odbc_connect("Prod_Schedule", "", "");
if (!$conn) {
    exit("Connection Failed: $conn");
}

$sql="SELECT `ITEM`, `DESCRIPTION`, `CUS_LOC_NAME`, `MECH_REL_BY`, `PM_DESIGN`, `SHIP_ACTUAL`, `HPL`, `WO_LINE`, `SO` FROM `Schedule` WHERE `HPL` <> 'PART' AND (LEFT(`DESCRIPTION`,6)=?) AND (LEFT(`CUS_LOC_NAME`,6)=?)";

$stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, $sql);
$params = array("value for first ?", "value for second ?");
$result = odbc_execute($stmt, $params);

if ($result) {
    odbc_result_all($stmt);
}
?>
```

(Who would have guessed there would be a dedicated function for printing a result set as an HTML table!!?)

Comment: Thanks miken. Sorry for the confusion